# Can't require remark and rehype plugins for gatsby-plugin-mdx

Tags: gatsby, remarkjs, gatsby-plugin-mdx

I was trying to follow the [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-mdx/#rehype-plugins) on including rehype plugins for gatsby-plugin-mdx. Specifically I was trying to use the `rehype-slug` plugin. I installed the packaged with npm and set my `gatsby.config.js` file to

```js
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    siteUrl: "https://www.yourdomain.tld",
    title: "test Website",
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-mdx",
      options:{
        rehypePlugins: [
          require("rehype-slug")
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
};
```

However upon running `gatsby develop` I encouter the following error:
`Error: [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\User\Documents\test-site\node_modules\rehype-slug\index.js require() of ES modules is not supported.`

I encouter similar problems when trying to use the `remark-math` and `rehype-katex` plugins. I'm using version 3.13.0 of the Gatsby CLI. The problem persists even with a completely new website. Any help with this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: Until gatsby resolves the issue with esm, downgrading rehype-slug to 4.0.1 make it work.

Comment: @Nik Sumeiko you should add that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it will work but, instead of using require from ES modules have you tried something like:

```
import slug from 'rehype-slug'

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    siteUrl: "https://www.yourdomain.tld",
    title: "test Website",
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-mdx",
      options:{
        rehypePlugins: [
          slug 
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
};
```

*Based on: https://github.com/rehypejs/rehype-slug*

Or directly importing in inside `rehypePlugins` as a dynamic import.

---

I've made a little bit of research and I found that dynamic imports are not supported because you can't access the value in the callback, so waiting for the import is not a solution either nor using an [ES module](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/23705#issuecomment-834122710).

However, the final solution (or at least the temporary working one) with your exact same use-case can be found in this [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/31599#discussioncomment-1239988):

> Update: I got the update to `rehype-slug@5.0.0` in my `gatsby-config.js` working by installing [`esm`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm) and [`patch-package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) and:
>
> 1. Modifying the `gatsby-config.js` as follows (to allow `require()` with the pure ES Modules)
>
>    ```
>    require = require('esm')(module);
>
>    module.exports = {
>      plugins: [
>        {
>          resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
>          options: {
>            rehypePlugins: [
>              require('rehype-slug').default,
>    ```
> 2. Try running the Gatsby dev server and see what breaks. It will throw an error either like this:
>
>    ```
>      Error: Must use import to load ES Module: /Users/k/p/project/node_modules/rehype-slug/index.js
>      require() of ES modules is not supported.
>      require() of /Users/k/p/project/node_modules/rehype-slug/index.js from /Users/k/p/project/gatsby-config.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
>      Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /Users/k/p/project/node_modules/rehype-slug/package.json.
>    ```
>
>    ...or like this:
>
>    ```
>      Error: /Users/k/p/project/gatsby-config.js:1
>      Error: Must use import to load ES Module: /Users/k/p/project/node_modules/rehype-slug/index.js
>    ```
> 3. Make a note of the location of the pure ES Modules package so that you can locate the `package.json` file corresponding to the pure ESM package and manually remove the line with `"type": "module",` like this:
>
>    ```
>    -  "type": "module",
>    ```
> 4. Run `yarn patch-package <pkg name> --exclude '^$'`, which will record the changes that you have made in the `package.json` file (to be reapplied by `patch-package` every time that you run `yarn` or `npm install`). Examples:
>
>    ```sh
>    # For a top-level dependency
>    yarn patch-package rehype-slug --exclude '^$'
>
>    # For a transitive dependency
>    yarn patch-package rehype-slug/unist-util-visit --exclude '^$'
>    ```
> 5. Run the Gatsby dev server again, and repeat step 3 and 4 for every pure ESM package.
>
> At that point, I could start the Gatsby dev server with the new pure ESM dependency versions.
>
> cc @Ir1d @kimbaudi @wardpeet @LekoArts
>
> Caveat: In my specific case, I needed to also patch one of the dependencies (`hast-util-heading-rank`) because I was getting an undefined `node.tagName`, but I think this is unrelated to this problem - probably related to a different issue.

*All credits to the magician involved*

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler and more elegant solution in the same [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/31599#discussioncomment-1754627)

Create `require-esm.js` in the root folder (same place as package.json):

```js
// Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71344589/2078908

const esm = require('esm')
const fs = require('fs')
const Module = require('module')

// Node: bypass [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]
const orig = Module._extensions['.js']
Module._extensions['.js'] = function (module, filename) {
  try {
    return orig(module, filename)
  } catch (e) {
    const content = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8')
    module._compile(content, filename)
  }
}

const _esmRequire = esm(module, {
  cjs: true,
  mode: 'all',
})

// don't pollute Module
Module._extensions['.js'] = orig

module.exports = function esmRequire(id) {
  return _esmRequire(id).default
}
```

Then use it in `gatsby-config.js` like this:

```js
require.esm = require('./require-esm')

module.exports = {
        .......
        {
            resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
            options: {
                extensions: ['.mdx', '.md'],
                rehypePlugins: [
                    // Generate heading ids for rehype-autolink-headings
                    [require.esm('rehype-slug')],
                    // To pass options, use a 2-element array with the
                    // configuration in an object in the second element
                    [require.esm('rehype-autolink-headings'), { behavior: "wrap" }],
                ],
            }
        },
        .......
}
```

**Update**

After some testing I've simplified code above to couple lines. It still works in my setup.

Use `require.esm(...)` in `gatsby-config.js` like this:

```js
const requireEsm = require('esm')(module)
require.esm = id => requireEsm(id).default

module.exports = {
                .......
                rehypePlugins: [
                    // Generate heading ids for rehype-autolink-headings
                    [require.esm('rehype-slug')],
                    .......
}
```